# ¿JList tiene un límite de elementos o items, y si lo tiene, cuál es el valor de ese límite?

Tags: java

hago esta pregunta ya que no la pude encontrar en ningún foro. Es mi primer vez que hago una pregunta en un foro, así que perdón si me mando alguna, soy muy nuevo en esto de los foros.
Bueno, no voy a poner código por que creo que no hace falta, sé que me van a entender. Tengo un JList que lleno con objetos que los busco en la base de datos, o sea lista=new JList(listaDeTipoDefaultListModel), la cuestión es que esa lista va a ir creciendo día a día, digamos que va a ir acrecentándose de a 50 por día, entonces necesito saber si algún día alcanzará un límite (si lo hay) haciendo fallar el programa. Con JComboBox tenía la misma duda, pero leí por ahí  que habían echo pruebas cargándolo hasta 60000 objetos y no había problemas

Comment: Lo primero, bienvenido a SO. Como segundo, estructura mejor las preguntas para que sean mas legibles. Si sueltas un troncho denso, desmotiva y no te lo leerán. Mirate los guias de como preguntar en SO para formatear correctamente. Y ahora respondiendo, probablemente el `Jlist` le pase como al `JcomboBox` y no tenga limite.

Comment: Gracias Cadeq por responder de inmediato. Voy a esperar a ver si alguien tiene más info al respecto, para estar más seguro